# Python, matplolib, using imshow and memmap to display large data set

Tags: python, display, large-data

I am using imshow from matplotlib to display 2D gray scale data set.
As the data set is important (~1Gb), I display only part of it.
To explore the rest, I want to use the pan/zoom button from matplotlib.
Loading all and then defining the region of interest using xlim()/ylim() is quite slow but allows for exploring all the data set

On the other hand defining  a region of interest and restricting teh visible area creates a different issue: using the pan button the surrounding of ROI is displayed as white.
I expect to see the data

I tough about using memmap to load only part of the dataset, but do not see how to link that to the  imshow axes.

Any suggestions?

Sindary

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the shape of the memmapped array
shape = (1000, 1000000)  # Shape of the dataset

# Generate a random 2D dataset
data = np.random.rand(1000,1000000)
# Save the dataset to a binary file
file_path = 'data.bin'
data.tofile(file_path)

# Memory-map the file containing the dataset
data = np.memmap(file_path, dtype=np.float64, mode='r', shape=shape)

# Define the region of interest
start_row = 20
end_row = 80
start_col = 30
end_col = 70
roi = data[start_row:end_row, start_col:end_col]

# Create a figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Display the region of interest using imshow
img = ax.imshow(roi, cmap='viridis', extent=[start_col, end_col, end_row, start_row], aspect='auto')
plt.colorbar(img)
plt.title('Region of Interest')


# Display the plot
plt.show()
```